# Почему не меняется типы в Numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Код:

```
import numpy as np
arr_1 = np.random.random(5) * 100
arr_1.astype(np.int32)
print(arr_1)
```

Я не могу применить **astype** и **dtype**, хотя arr_1 является <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Не понимаю почему, помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr_1.astype(np.int32)
```

У вас типовая ошибка - результат никуда не присвоен. Надо его присвоить:

```
arr_1 = arr_1.astype(np.int32)
```

Тогда на выходе `print(arr_1)` будут `int`-ы, например:

```
[18  1 97 46 41]
```